# Autofac, (Fluent) nHibernate, ISession "Session is closed!" intermittently

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, dependency-injection, fluent-nhibernate, autofac

I'm having random "Session is closed!" errors with the following configuration of Autofac and Fluent nHibernate:

Global.asax.cs:

```
builder.Register(x => new NHibernateConfigurator().GetSessionFactory()).SingleInstance();
builder.Register(x => x.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

NHibernateConfigurator.cs

```
    public class NHibernateConfigurator
{
    public Configuration Configure()
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.SessionFactory()
            .Proxy.Through<ProxyFactoryFactory>()
            .Integrate.Using<Oracle10gDialect>();

        FluentConfiguration fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure(configuration);
        fluentConfiguration.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<UserMap>());

        return fluentConfiguration.BuildConfiguration();
    }

    public ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory()
    {
        var configuration = Configure();
        return configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

SomeController.cs:

```
private readonly IRepository repository;

public SomeController(IRepository repository)
{
this.repository = repository
}

[Transaction]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var result = repository.GetUsers();
    return View(result);
}
```

TransactionAttribute.cs

```
public class TransactionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISession>().BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        ITransaction currentTransaction = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISession>().Transaction;

        if (currentTransaction.IsActive)
        {
            if (filterContext.Exception != null && filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
            {
                currentTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        ITransaction currentTransaction = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISession>().Transaction;

        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
        try
        {
            if (currentTransaction.IsActive)
            {
                if (filterContext.Exception != null && !filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
                {
                    currentTransaction.Rollback();
                }
                else
                {
                    currentTransaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            currentTransaction.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

IRepository.cs:

```
public interface IRepository 
{
    IList<User> GetUsers();     
}
```

Repository.cs:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private readonly ISession session;

    public Repository(ISession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public IList<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return session.QueryOver<User>().List();
    }
}
```

This current set-up works, but seems to fail intermittently (after a few page reloads or restarts of Cassini) with GetUsers throwing "Session is closed!" errors. I thought registering the ISessionFactory on an InstancePerHttpRequest would avoid these issues. No luck. Any ideas? New to nHibernate and Autofac, so if I failed to post enough relevant information, let me know.

Comment: Are you using MVC 3? Is transaction management managed in a action filter?

Comment: MVC 3, yes. Transaction management, yes. Forgot to include that snippet - added it in.

Comment: Had the same issue. Seems to be an MVC 3 issue, can't find the link to the info, but move the ISession to rather be injected to the controller. Fixed up. Better to rather have control over the session too so you don't have to wait until the request closes before you have a problem that you may need to display in your UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears my configuration is working perfectly for any nHibernate calls outside of my custom membership providers and custom role providers - they are the issue as far as I can tell, which means this question isn't really addressing the issue.

Comment: Please, add some logging to check that action filters. We only found this out in a prod environment with HEAVY traffic being thrown at it

Answer (score 0):

How is your `Repository` registered? Is it `InstancePerHttpRequest` (which is should be), or `Singleton` (which it shouldn't).

Comment: Currrently, as "builder.RegisterType<Repository().As<IRepository>();". Attaching .InstancePerHttpRequest() after As<IRepository>() didn't resolve the issue (assuming that's what you meant).

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem using MVC 3 action filters and seems they are cached quite aggressively in MVC 3 and found that sessions were not always being opened as OnActionExecuted not always fire.

Move your session into the controller constructor like so:

```
 public SomeController(
        ISession session,
        ILogger logger,
        IRepository<Something> someRepository )
    {
        _session = session;
        _logger = logger;
        _someRepository = someRepository;
    }
```

In your action where you want to wrap a transaction:

```
using (var transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
{
   // do something with your repository
   _someRepository.Add(new Something());
   transaction.commit();
}
```